# adjusted rand index (ARI)

Tags: machine-learning

Why using  adjusted rand index (ARI) and normalized mutual information (NMI) in clustering methods results in a better measurement than simple test score(such as MSE)? 
I understand that which point belongs to which cluster is important in clustering algorithms, and labeling is arbitrary .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You answered yourself - there is no "MSE" for clustering, since MSE is defined only if you know the **value** of the dependant variable. In clustering it is not only arbitrarly assigned, but there is no even the concept of a "number", and MSE is regression metric, it operates on numbers, not classes. Now, why not just use Accuracy then by simply computing all possible permutations of labeling? Well this is (almost) exactly what RandIndex is, even though it originated in the different society, and has different name, it is very closely related to mapping between cluster and label. So what is Adjusted Rand Index? Nothing but RandIndex / (almost) Accuracy with a correction which tells you how completely random classifier behaves. So it is literally a transformation of accuracy metric normalized by the accuracy of a random classifier.

These "small differences" simply take into consideration fact, that clustering has some additional properties like:

- number of clusters (labels) is not given a priori
- you need to take a correction with trivial models, which might be hard to easily figure out (for classification it is usually very simple to say what is the accuracy of trivial model)

Especially the first part matters, consider clustering:

```
clustering   [o o o o][o o o o][o o o o ]
truth        [o o o o  o o o o][o o o o ]
```

The only "bad thing" that happened is that we splitted one class into 2 parts. If we use accuracy we get 75% (since one half is simply considered "bad") but if we take into account rand index, it will actually assign much higher score than for:

```
clustering   [o][o][o][o][o o o o][o o o o ]
truth        [o  o  o  o  o o o o][o o o o ]
```

which with accuracy would also yield 75%. And I would argue that the first clustering is indeed better than the second.

In other words, these metrics are closely related to the classical classification metrics, they simply introduce additional flavors to differentiate between (mostly) clusterings with different number of clusters. The main reason here is that in clustering you care about **structure**, not point-wise labels.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.